# Material Table causing 401 Unauthorized error if page refreshed

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-core, angular-material

I have got my mat-table showing retrieved data from an httpget method in the .Net Core server side. However, when the page is refreshed or the table was initiated in the main component, I get the following error:

```
NodeInvocationException: Http failure response for http://localhost:5649/api/Project/GetProjectList: 401 Unauthorized
```

- Component:

  ```
  @Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'}) 

  export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  displayedColumns = ['ProjectId', 'ProjectTitle'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Project>(); 

  constructor(private projectSerivce: ProjectService, private http: 
  HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
  this.URLstring = baseUrl; 
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.projectSerivce.getProj().subscribe(data => {
   console.log("Total No: "+data.length);
  this.dataSource.data = data });}
  }
  ```
- ProjectService

  ```
      @Injectable()
      export class ProjectService {
      baseUrlH: string;
      constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
      this.baseUrlH = baseUrl
      }

      getProj(): Observable<Project[]> { 
      const href = this.baseUrlH + 'api/Project/GetProjectList';
      return this.http.get<Project[]>(href).map(Response => 
      <Project[]>Response); 
      }
      }
  ```
- DataSource

  ```
  export class projDataSource implements DataSource<any> {

  private recProj = new BehaviorSubject<Project[]>([]);

  constructor(private projService: ProjectService) {
  }

  connect(): Observable<Project[]> {
      this.projService.getProj().subscribe({ next: (value) => { this.recProj.next(value)}})
      return Observable.merge(this.recProj);
  }

  disconnect(){        
  }
  }
  ```
- Server Side API

  ```
  [HttpGet("[action]")]
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public async Task<IEnumerable<Project>> GetProjectList()
   {
  IEnumerable<Project> ProjectList;
  using (TAMS_DBcontext db = new TAMS_DBcontext())
  {
  ProjectList = await db.Project.ToListAsync();
  }
  return ProjectList;
  }
  ```

Why the data would be successfully retrieved when I navigated to this component but would not re-initiate if page is refreshed? Also why the error would appear if the table got initiated in the main component when the app is launched?

- Server Side: .Net Core 2.0 (Windows Authentication)
- Front Side: Angular 5.2.3

Answer (score 0):

The 401 Unauthorized Error is an HTTP response status code indicating that the request sent by the client could not be authenticated.

Comment: True but why I was able to retrieve the data before I refresh the browser?

Comment: i thing you are not storing the data

Comment: I'm storing the data into the datasource object

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en   install this plugin and enable 
 CORS and try again bro

Answer (score 0):

**declare the data variable as a type of Project**

@Component({

selector: 'home',

templateUrl: './home.component.html'

})

data:Project;

export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

displayedColumns = ['ProjectId', 'ProjectTitle'];

dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

constructor(private projectSerivce: ProjectService, private http:

HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {

this.URLstring = baseUrl;

}

ngAfterViewInit() {

this.projectSerivce.getProj().subscribe(data => {

console.log("Total No: "+data.length);

this.data = data });}

}

Comment: According to the material docs, I need to use MatTableDataSource as a datasource for the table. Your suggestion can work with other controls.

Answer (score 0):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.projectSerive.getProj().map((simpleItems) => {
        console.log("LL:" + simpleItems.length);
        this.dataSource.data = simpleItems;
        return simpleItems; 
    }).catch((exception) => {
            console.log(exception);
            return of(exception);
        }).subscribe(data => {});
}
```

The above change has solved the problem. Storing the data from `.map()` instead of `subscribe()` was the solution although I am not sure why!